# Validate request param names for optional fields - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

If you have an endpoint described like this :

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello(@RequestParam(name= "my_id", required=false) myId, @RequestParam(name= "my_name") myName){
    // return something
}
```

**Issue:**

The consumers of this endpoint could send invalid param names in the request;

`/hello?my_name=adam&a=1&b=2` and it will work normally.

**Goal:**

Be able to validate optional request parameters names, using a proper way to do it.

**Actual solution:**

I've implemented a solution (For me it's not the right solution), where I've  extends a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and register it in the `WebMvcConfigurer` :

```
/**
 *
 * Interceptor for unknown request parameters
 *
 */
public class MethodParamNamesHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> queryParams = Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());

        MethodParameter[] methodParameters = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodParameters();
        Map<String, String> methodParametersMap = new HashMap<>();
        if(Objects.nonNull(methodParameters)){
            methodParametersMap = Arrays.stream(methodParameters)
                    .map(m -> m.getParameter().getName())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),Function.identity()));
        }
        Set<String> unknownParameters = collectUnknownParameters(methodParametersMap, queryParams);
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(unknownParameters)){
            throw new InvalidParameterNameException("Invalid parameters names", unknownParameters);
        }

        return super.preHandle(request,response,handler);
    }

    /**
     * Extract unknown properties from a list of parameters
     * @param allParams
     * @param queryParam
     * @return
     */
    private Set<String> collectUnknownParameters(Map<String, String> allParams, List<String> queryParam){
        return queryParam.stream()
                .filter(param -> !allParams.containsKey(param))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

**Drawbacks:**

The drawbacks of this solution is that it's based on method parameters,
It will take the name `myId` instead of taking `my_id`, this could have a workaround by transforming the uppercase word to snake-case; but this is not a good solution because you can have something like this : `sayHello(@RequestParam(name= "my_id", required=false) anotherName)`.

**Question:**
Is there a proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: Get the optional annotation from the parameter and check the name parameter of it.

Comment: You can try `@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqParam` to capture all request params otherwise you can use Spring Validator

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire this will bring me params sent in the request, and in my actual solution it's equivalent to `ArrayList<String> queryParams = Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());`

Comment: Can't you just do this? public String sayHello(@RequestParam(name= "my_id", required=false) Long myId, @RequestParam(name= "my_name") String myName)

Comment: @RobScully sorry I don't understand your proposition !

Comment: can you try @Validated on class and check ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to avoid parsing 2 times the `((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodParameters()`, first time to get the name/value from the annotation and then second time (if name or value are not specified) to get the method param name and then transform it to snake-case if not.

Comment: @Mak It was the first thing I've tried

Comment: Well then there is 2 way I can see , Either you read all parameter from request in handler or interceptor. Either you create dto with required parameter and take that dto in request param with @valid annotation

Comment: Why would you need to parse twice? Just make an if. If the name isn't specified in the annotation use the parameter name. You don't need 2 iterations for that.

Comment: @Mark I wanted to be sure if there is/isn't a "simple" way to do it, This goes on a shared utility and will be used by many microservices, there is no way to update user contract (endpoints). So I think I'll use Interceptor handler for the moment.

Comment: Also you probably need to question if you really want this solution. What if you need to add request parameters because of security (like an API_KEY) which is processed in a general way. That would now be blocked as it isn't an argument of your method. What to do with parameters that aren't simple types and converted otherwise or things that are `@ModelAttribute`s, those will now all fail because of this additional validation being done.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you on this, what would be the solution then !

Comment: Do you really want this kind of validation, as I see more problems with it than it solves. Why is it illegal to add additional parameters to the request? They are ignored anyway, could be that an older version of your API had 3 params, and now you only have to, this would break the old URL (while it still is kind of valid).

Comment: This kind of behaviour could lead to a misunderstood situation, when you return a filtered result based on your parameters, as you can misspell the param name in the uri, and still got the result from the service endpoint